# Why does PHP's "trigger_error" return true?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I use the error handling for my custom functions, and notice all three user error types (NOTICE, WARNING and ERROR) all return *true*.

I used the **trigger_error** function to escape a function when it has been incorrectly processed (eg. invalid data inserted). I thought the best way to escape the function is to use:

```
return trigger_error('Error notice here');
```

The problem is, errors return *true*. Although not all my functions return *true* upon success, it seems to me like this could be used in the future (hence, *false* would represent an error).

Is there a reason why this function would return *true*, or am I following bad practice in exiting invalid functions?

I know a solution for this could be:

```
trigger_error('Error notice here');
return false;
```

But I thought there would be a more elegant method. Hopefully there is, if not, some insight into best practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns `TRUE` because the operation of triggering the error was successful. It would be `FALSE` if you specified an invalid error type to the second argument.

If you want to return `TRUE` and trigger an error (which, by the way, makes no sense the way I see it) in one line you can do this:

```
return !trigger_error('Error notice here');
```

Incidentally, if you trigger an `E_USER_ERROR` I doubt the code that evaluates the return value would ever be reached, because the error would be fatal unless you have registered an error handler to catch it.

If you want to exit a function with an error message that you can handle in your code, you should use an [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). Although whether these make sense in the context of a procedural function is highly debatable.

Comment: Thank you, exceptions appear to be a much more appropriate solution, also preventing a function from proceeding. I have read up on the load required for an exception rather than an error. It appears substantial, and makes me wonder if it is best practice to use them constantly.

For example, a function that inserts a new user comment, and would need to check if the user ID is found, if the post ID exists that is being commented on, etc, should have an exception thrown at every point of failure?

Comment: @Rhys It really depends on the use case. Exceptions are the OOP way of error handling, which is why I said `...whether these make sense in the context of a procedural function is highly debatable`. If you decide you need to halt the execution of a function, you have two options: `return` or `throw`. In purely procedural code, `return` usually makes more sense, in OOP code it's usually the other way around. But the example to mention is a good use case for exceptions, because an exception can include a message describing what the error is, whereas returning `FALSE` cannot as easily.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about more elegant solutions than `trigger_error()`.

I would suggest that a more elegant method might be to throw an exception instead of triggering an error.